# Windows virtualenv created via GitBash using system python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, virtualenv, git-bash

I've noticed that my virtualenvs created in GitBash are not using the venv's python/pip executables, and pip is trying to install things to the system site packages. I'm sure this was working correctly last time I checked, so I'm not sure what's gone/going wrong, but it's perplexing me, as from point of view I've done everything right.

What have I missed?

My steps to reproduce are pretty straight forward:

```sh
chris@windows-pc  MINGW64 ~
$ which python
/c/Program Files/Python37/python

chris@windows-pc  MINGW64 ~
$ which pip
/c/Program Files/Python37/Scripts/pip

chris@windows-pc  MINGW64 ~
$ python -m venv /c/venvs/test

chris@windows-pc  MINGW64 ~
$ . /c/venvs/test/Scripts/activate
(test)
chris@windows-pc  MINGW64 ~
$ which python
/c/Program Files/Python37/python
(test)
chris@windows-pc MINGW64 ~
$ which pip
/c/Program Files/Python37/Scripts/pip
(test)
chris@windows-pc  MINGW64 ~
```

I've tried the above commands with both `.` and `source` and the behaviour is the same.

- python is 3.7.3
- windows is 10
- I'm not sure how to determine the gitBash version on this system

Comment: I reproduce the steps and everything is working right, maybe the git bash is broken, do you try to install it again? Or maybe the virtualenv package

Comment: It's entirely possible there's a bug in the Gitbash, unfortunately the system is locked down so I can't change it. the virtualenv library is the standard one that is included in python 3.7.3

Answer (score 8):

I discovered the issue was that there was an error inside the activate script, which had a windows style path (`C:\path\to\env`) for the VIRTUAL_ENV environment variable.

As a result, the path was being set incorrectly and the virtualenv's Scripts directory wasn't being correctly added to the path (it was there, but the colon in `C:\` and the backwards slashes meant that entry wasn't valid).

Manually editing the activate script and changing to a unix style path resolved the issue.

This appears to be a bug in the `venv` module in python when run in this gitbash/windows environment

Answer (score 0):

You need to use source if you are using gitbash in windows to activate your virtualenv

```
source /PATH/TO/VIRTUALENV/SCRIPTS/activate
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't appear to make a difference (I updated the question accordingly)